# Un-merge the tags for CFScript and ColdFusion

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

> I am no longer proposing this feature request. I'm older and wiser now. Unfortunately it can not be deleted, it's here for historical reference.

Stack Overflow merges [cfscript](/questions/tagged/cfscript) with the [coldfusion](/questions/tagged/coldfusion) tag. [ColdFusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion), however, is not [CFScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFScript), nor are CFScript and ColdFusion synonymous with [cfml](/questions/tagged/cfml). [CFML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ColdFusion_Markup_Language) and CFScript are two languages that run on ColdFusion, but they're not synonymous with ColdFusion either.

ColdFusion is the engine while CFScript is its scripting language; CFML is a tag based language that is different from CFScript. CFML and CFScript share some functions, but they can be vastly different:

For example, a query in both:

```
// CFScript
myQuery = new Query(datasource=variables.myDSN);
myQuery.setSQl(SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE bar.id = 1);
myQuery = myQuery.execute().getResult();
```

```
<!--- CFML --->
<cfquery name="myQuery" datasource="#variables.myDSN#">
    SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE bar.id = 1 
</cfquery>
```

I write my code using CFScript and most of my questions are CFScript specific. They are unrelated to the ColdFusion engine, or CFML, and I don't want my [cfscript](/questions/tagged/cfscript) tag lumped under [coldfusion](/questions/tagged/coldfusion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty active in the ColdFusion tag, and I don't agree with the request to remove the tag synonym.

Adobe ColdFusion is aiming for one-to-one tag/script compatibility, and I think the other CFML engines are too.

I don't think the fragmentation would assist anyone. There's not so much traffic in that tag (unfortunately) that CFScript questions would get missed.